# bootstrap css textbox and button positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Code contains text box and button

**HTML**:

```
   <div id="input-collection" class="input-group input-group-lg">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i>
          </span>
              <input id= "url-input-box" type="url" class="form-control" name = "url" placeholder="http://www.example.com">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button id="submit-url-btn" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Go</button>
          </span>
</div>
```

which shows button and texbox like:

[image: text button align]

I changed `margin-top` and `margin-left` in all above class but no change.

Where I need to make change here?

Comment: I find divs easier to work with than spans when it comes to positioning. Is there any reason why you are using spans?

Comment: I am using bootstrap demo examples to implement,  it containing spans si I carry on with same

Comment: Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your actual markup and any extra CSS you may have added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebug (or chrome developer tools - Ctrl+Shift+J)

Look at the margin-bottom settings of: submit-url-btn (the  tag)

against the margin-bottom of the url-input-box (span)

It seems that the button has a high value on margin-bottom. set both to 0 and see how they are positioned.